# How make a request when I update a jquery mobile slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to make a SQL request when the user update the value of the slider made on jquery mobile?

I just implemented that code:

```
<form id="range_search" action="range_search?" method="post" style="text-align: center;" rel="external">
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="15" min="0" max="100"  />
</form>
```

I use that code but `taphold` doesn't work

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider").taphold(function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried binding to the `change` event?

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").bind('change', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/slider/events.html